# Invoke static method to close form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, this, static-methods

I have two Windows Forms - `Form1` and `Form2`. I need to close `Form1` from a button click event in `Form2`. How do I do it if the method in `Form1` is `static`?

**Form1**

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {     
        public static void CloseForm()
        {
            this.Close();
        }       
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.CloseForm();            
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error

> Keyword "this" is not valid in static property, static method or
>   static field initializer.

I have heard of `Single-ton`, `Multi-ton` concepts. Is there a need to convert the class or is there any easy way to handle this?

**EDIT**

There can be multiple instances of `Form1` and `Form2`. Consider the below situation.

- User opens `Form1`, then opens `Form2` from `Form1`, in button click of `Form2`, `Form1` should be closed **(INSTANCE 1)**
- User can again open another instance of `Form1`, then opens `Form2` from `Form1`, in button click of `Form2`, `Form1` should be closed. **(INSTANCE 2)**

ie, When the user clicks button in `Form2` **(INSTANCE 2)**, only one `Form1` **(INSTANCE 2)** should be closed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you don't need `closeForm` method to close `Form1`!

Comment: this referres to the non-static instance of the class. Also forms are non-static in C#. If you want to close another form simply have a static variable declared of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to close only the Form1 that opened Form2**, you must pass Form1 as a parameter to Form2's constructor:

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1;

        public Form2(Form1 form1) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.form1 = form1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.form1.Close();            
        }
    }
}
```

**If you want to close all instances of Form1:**

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().ToList())
                form.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its getting closed. But throwing error - Collection modified

Comment: Its working fine for your edited answer. I have one more question. Does this close all forms named Form1?

Comment: I had tried passing constructor and setting that in a global variable. In my app, the object is getting cleared(not because of your code) and I cannot use that object to Close the form.

Comment: Don't set a global variable. You must set an instance variable in the Form2.

Comment: The issue got solved. I had declared **Form1 form1=new Form1()** in class. When I changed to **Form1 form1;**, the issue got solved. Now I am able to access the values in **obj** at any point. Thank you so much. :) @Juan Lopes

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't have a `this` reference in a static method. Which instance would it be referring to?

You can make it a singleton, but this sounds like a design smell.

I see no reason the method should be static. If `Form2` needs to know about `Form1`, then it should have a reference to a `Form1` instance.

Alternatively, if `Form2` should not know about `Form1`, but `Form1` knows about `Form2`, then `Form2` can fire an event which signals `Form1` to close.

Comment: Your update only validates the reasoning I've given. `Form2` should accept a `Form1` instance in its constructor and store a reference to it, or the other way around using events.

Answer (score 0):

Overthinking, close it directly.
An instance of a form cannot be closed by a static method, since the class (static methods are part of the class) doesn't know about the instance.

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {       
        Form1 form1;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.form1.Close();             
        }
    }
}
```

Value `form1` can be set via the constructor or via a property from the caller.

Comment: I am not sure this works without passing `Form1` as argument in constructing `Form2`! am I wrong?

Comment: If I understand your edit, every form should be able to close its creator. My answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling in wrong way

check following

```
namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {     
        //no need of CloseForm
    }
}


namespace WinClose
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Form1 o = new Form();//instance needed
            Form1 o= Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>        
            if(o != null)
            {    
              o.Close();       
            }     
        }
    }
}
```